# Python: My server mail is sent to spam

Tags: python, email, smtp, sendmail, smtplib

I'm trying to send email verification emails from an app I'm writing. I'm running on Linode using `server = smtplib.SMTP()` and `server.sendmail()`. For some reason, gmail is marking these messages as spam.

My mail template is:

```
{% if define('From', 'CQ <Invite@campusquery.com>') or define('Reply-To', 'noreply@campusquery.com') or define('Subject', "CQ: You've been invited to our beta!") %}{{fail()}}{% end %}

msg goes here
```

It also worked before when I made CQ  be invite@campusquery.com instead. However, when this way does not allow me to define a sender.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What server are you sending from? There are tons of other factors involved like IP blacklists, rate of messages, whether users have marked you as spam, DNS/reverse DNS, SPF records.

You might consider signing up for an account with litmus.com to test your emails and see how you're performing on spam lists, and what you can do to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the "From" address would need to be a valid email address--e.g., have `<some name>`, an `@` and a valid `host` like in `bob@example.com`--in order for GMail to not consider it spam.

Comment: RFC2822 route-addr syntax is common and acceptable.  I'd worry more about (a) the uppercase "I" I most often see as in spam, and (b) the Subject also resembles a lot of spam I see.  Rephrase it to not be quite as much of a trigger?

Comment: Oh, I think the formatting was broken when I read it so I didn't realize it had the `<blah@blah.com>` in the from field.